# IOException occured ReadtoEnd in reading Textfile function

Tags: c#, filestream, ioexception

I'm running into a strange problem while reading from a Textfile on VS2019.I know where is wrong,but i cannot fix it.

The path1 is used to store an Absolute path to a Textfile which has been built.Only this variable to store path.

The richtextbox is to show the content read from the Textfile.Clean it Before using.

```
  String path1=this.textBox1.Text;
  this.richTextBox1.Clear();
```

The fifth row is the problem.

When i debug the code,the value of sr.ReadtoEnd() shows "This expression can cause side effects and will not be evaluated".

```
                try
                {
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path1, FileMode.Open);
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default);
                    this.richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();//What's wrong????
                    sr.Close();
                    fs.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Read....");
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to read...");
                }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It is a debugger notification, it has nothing to do with the code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not wrong, that warning says that displaying that information requires calling some code, and that the debugger refuses to do it because it does not know if calling that function is fine or is problematic. Consider having a look at the value of `this.richTextBox1.Text` instead after that line has been executed.

Comment: After debugging the code,there is nothing in this.richTextBox1.Text.Because it cannot reach to the step......